# Transforming coordinate system in ArcMap gives Warning 001293?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap

I have lats and lons in EUREF FIN35 system and I'm trying to transform it to WGS1984. Here is and example of my data.

```
6906030,3689220
6906269,3691008
6907518,3691012
6908265,3690256
6908630,3689801
6909489,3689358
6907607,3690761
6907880,3690409
6907214,3690251
```

And I'm using the ArcToolbox like below:
[image]

However, it gives the error

[image]

Can someone please let me know what's wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: Your input coordinates definitely do not look like latitudes and longitudes. Using DD_2 here cannot work. If your data is in FIN35, you need to specify that projection and UTM notation as input coordinate format. You will have a bit of formatting to do beforehand, because ArcGIS expects a single text string in one field, like this example: `35N 351192 6841977`.

Comment: Please always provide error and warning messages as text rather than pictures. That one is a warning message and not an error.