# How to format coordinates as preparation for transformation to WGS1984 in ArcMap 10.8?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, convert, format

I have a pointshape with a lot of points, containing X and Y values projected in krasovsky_1940_albers. I want to transform the projection to WGS1984 and tried to use the Tool "Convert Coordinate Notation" but it only response with the Warning 001293:coordinate conversion failed.

I found a thread with a similar problem ([Transforming coordinate system in ArcMap gives Warning 001293?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311587/transforming-coordinate-system-in-arcmap-gives-warning-001293/378541#378541)) where  FSimardGIS suggests to format my coordinates before the conversion. Since I am very new to arcmap, I don't have any idea how to to such things. Is there a tool or a method to use the field calculator for such things? I would like to it not point by point because it would take to much time. I tried:

[POINT_X].SetFormat( [ + | - | E | W ] <DD.dd> [ + | - | E | W ]).AsString

in field calculator, but it did not work.

Here is a Screenshot of my CCN input:

[image]

[image]

In addition I tried:

Convert a raster to point (change the reference system), export (and inport) the attribute table of the point shape, then set the coordinate system to WGS1984 under DISPLAY X,Y, Export the Events as layer and inport the new Point shape, and it also shows me that the reference system is WGS1984, but when I calculate the coordinates by calculate field geometry in decimal degree, I only get 0 as an outcome.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hello @DAFZ, can you add a screenshot of the input and output parameters used in the CCN tool?

Comment: Thank your for your quick response @Yogi! I added a picture

Comment: Have you tried using the Project tool and specify GCS_WGS_1984 as the output? If that works you can then simply use calculate geometry in 2 new fields for latitude and longitude.

Comment: Yes. I only get 0

Comment: There may be an issue with one of the previous actions that you performed. Make sure to use your original point layer and Project that layer directly, you don't need to perform any other actions in between. If your original point layer is diplayed correctly, and is in the correct crs, then this should be sufficient. Once your new point layer is created after Project, load it in a new mxd and calculate the x and y values.

Comment: Ah, I think I found the problematic step that you did: _set the coordinate system to WGS1984 under DISPLAY X,Y_. You can't transform coordinate systems by reimporting xy data and setting a new crs like this.

Comment: By doing this, you are telling the system that your (110260, 3820294) coordinates are actually longitudes and latitudes in WGS1984, which is not the case, and the reason why arcmap is unable to work with these. These are Krasovsky Albers and that's the crs you have to specify when you import your XY data. But that would lead you nowhere as you would be back to the starting point. Use the Project tool directly on your original point layer instead.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem!!!

Comment: Great, then I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change a coordinate reference system, you have to use a fuction that will actually recalculate your points from one system to another, such as the Project tool.

The problem here is that you set WGS84 as the crs when you imported your projected coordinates. By doing this, you are telling the system that your (110260, 3820294) coordinates are actually longitudes and latitudes in WGS1984, which is not the case, and the reason why ArcMap is unable to work with these.

Your coordinates are Krasovsky Albers and that's the crs you have to specify when you import XY data. But that would lead you nowhere as you would be back to the starting point. Instead, use the Project tool directly on your original point layer instead, specifying Krasovsky 1940 Albers as input crs, and GCS WGS 1984 as output crs, and this will perform the appropriate transformation. Then calculating geometry on this new layer will yield WGS84 long/lat coordinates.